# Selenium clicking next button programmatically until the last page

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

hi I'm new to web scraping and have been trying to use Selenium to scrape a [forum](https://forums.hardwarezone.com.sg/money-mind-210/hdb-fully-paid-up-5744914.html) in python

I am trying to get Selenium to click "Next" until the last page but I am not sure how to break the loop. and I having trouble with the locator:

When I locate the next button by **partial link**, the automated clicking will continue to next thread e.g page1->page2->next thread->page1 of next thread-->page2 of next thread

```
while True:
    next_link = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.PARTIAL_LINK_TEXT, "Next")))
    next_link.click()
```

When I locate the next button by **class name**, the automated clicking will click "prev" button when it reaches the last page

```
while True:
    next_link = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "prevnext")))
    next_link.click()
```

My questions are:

1. Which locator should I use? (by class or by partial link or any
   other suggestion?
2. How do I break the loop so it stops clicking when it reaches the
   last page?

Comment: Share HTML code for pagination block. Also share HTML for Next button both for cases when last page reached and not reached

Comment: You can use whatever selector you want if it works. I generally use id or xpath in such cases.
Insert an If statement with a condition that can determine the last page and insert a `break;` statement there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use below code to click Next button until the last page reached and break the loop if the button is not present:

```
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException

while True:
    try:
        WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.LINK_TEXT, "Next ›"))).click()
    except TimeoutException:
        break
```

Comment: thank you so much! this solved my issue. previously I realised my mistake was that I was using Next &rsaquo; instead of Next >

Answer (score 1):

1. You can use any locator which gives unique identification. Best practices says the following order.

   - Id
   - Name
   - Class Name
   - Css Selector
   - Xpath
   - Others
2. The come out of the while loop when it is not find the element you can use try block as given below. the break command is used for the same.

   ```
   while True:
       try:
           next_link = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "prevnext")))
           next_link.click()
       except TimeoutException:
           break
   ```

Comment: thank you. but by using "prevnext" it will create an endless clicking, because at the last page, there is a "Prev" button which is also located using "prevnext". this was my previous issue.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of things you need to consider as follows :

- There are two elements on the page with text as **Next** one on *Top* and another at the *Bottom*, so you need to decide with which element you desire to interact and construct a unique [Locator Strategy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890)
- Moving forward as you want to invoke `click()` on the element instead of *expected-conditions* as `presence_of_element_located()` you need to use `element_to_be_clickable()`.
- When there would be no element with text as **Next** you need to execute the remaining steps, so invoke the `click()` within **`try-catch`** block and incase of an exception `break` out.
- As per your requirement **xpath** as a *Locator Strategy* looks good to me.
- Here is the working code block :

  ```
  from selenium import webdriver
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

  options = webdriver.ChromeOptions() 
  options.add_argument("start-maximized")
  options.add_argument('disable-infobars')
  driver=webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options, executable_path=r'C:\Utility\BrowserDrivers\chromedriver.exe')
  driver.get("https://forums.hardwarezone.com.sg/money-mind-210/hdb-fully-paid-up-5744914.html")
  driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[@id='poststop' and @name='poststop']//following::table[1]//li[@class='prevnext']/a").click()
  while True:
      try :
          WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//a[@id='poststop' and @name='poststop']//following::table[1]//li[@class='prevnext']/a[contains(.,'Next')]"))).click()
      except :
          print("No more pages left")
          break
  driver.quit()
  ```
- Console Output :

  ```
  No more pages left
  ```